# Use masks to retrieve submatrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following code

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
a[[True,True,False],[True,True,False]]
```

What I expect is a submatrix

```
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

but what I get is

```
array([1, 5])
```

I have figured out a method to retrieve the submatrix

```
a[np.ix_([True,True,False],[True,True,False])]
```

My question:

> Any other way we can do this more elegantly?

Comment: Looks reasonably elegant to me.